# Excel - Two key value lists - Locate where Key is different but value is the same

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two key-value lists.

e.g

Table 1

```
ID      Value
1       Example A
2       Example B
```

and

Table 2

```
ID      Value
1       Example A
3       Example B
```

I need to know where the values match but the ID is different. In the above example, this would be Example B because in Table 1 it has the ID of 2 but in Table 2 it has the ID of 3

I believe I could use the INDEX or MATCH functions but I am not sure how to go about this?

Comment: What happens if there are repeat values against different ids within the same table (one of which - a later one might match across tables) ? Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order of the columns were switched, we could fairly easily use `VLOOKUP` here:

```
Sheet 1, Table 1
A              B      C
Example A      1
Example B      2      DIFFERENT

Sheet 2, Table 2
A              B
Example A      1
Example B      3
```

Enter the following formula into C1 on the first sheet with table 1:

```
=IF(B1=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A1:B2, 2, FALSE), ""), "", "DIFFERENT")
```

Note that you may have to adjust the cell references and ranges used in the formula.  For instance, I trivially assume that both tables only have two rows of data, when in fact they probably have more.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I keep om getting a reference error (#N/A) when I try this. When i use the calculation steps wizard, it looks like the issue is to do with the array in the VLOOKUP

Comment: @martpendle I can't see your worksheet/workbook, so I can't guess at what might be wrong.  If you had the exact setup which my answer assumes, what I suggest should be working for you.

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue occurs when a value from column A only exists on one of the sheets. For the vlookup to work the values need to match on both sheets. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: You may try wrapping the call to `VLOOKUP` using `IFERROR`.  The logic I used should result now in `DIFFERENT` being displayed if either the `Value` was matched, by the `ID`s did not match, _or_ the `Value` could not be looked up at all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in the same sheet you can use below simple formula to compare the cells.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this depends on the order of the data being the same in the two data sets

Answer (score 1):

Just for S&G:

VBA is unnecessary but I wanted to have a play with creating a basic UDF using .Net System.Collections `SortedList` class. This is based on the assumption that values do not repeat within a table (in terms of returning a correct result.).

Arg 1 *rng1* is the first table range excluding headers

Arg 2 *rng2* is the second table range excluding headers

Arg 3 *testValue* is a string value for the value to check has matching id across tables. You can rely on default member access by passing a single cell range in, or, explicitly pass a literal string.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
   Debug.Print MatchingKey([A2:B3], [D2:E3], [B3])
End Sub
Public Function MatchingKey(ByVal rng1 As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range, ByVal testValue As String) As Variant
    Dim aList As Object, bList As Object, aArray(), bArray(), i As Long

    If rng1.Columns.Count <> 2 Or rng2.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
        MatchingKey = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo errhand
    Set aList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    Set bList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    aArray = rng1.value
    bArray = rng2.value

    For i = LBound(aArray, 1) To UBound(aArray, 1)
        aList.Add aArray(i, 1), aArray(i, 2)
    Next
    For i = LBound(bArray, 1) To UBound(bArray, 1)
        bList.Add bArray(i, 1), bArray(i, 2)
    Next

    If Not aList.ContainsValue(testValue) Or Not bList.ContainsValue(testValue) Then
        MatchingKey = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    MatchingKey = aList.GetKey(aList.IndexOfValue(testValue)) = bList.GetKey(bList.IndexOfValue(testValue))
    Exit Function
errhand:
    MatchingKey = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

---

Example in sheet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with match formula.

H,G: Lookup Value (Table 2)

B,A: Lookup Array (Table 1)

ctrl+shift+Enter

```
{=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(H2=B2:B3)*(G2=A2:A3),0)),"Match","Not Match")}
```